# Full authentication is required to access this resource error message with Axios in React-native app

Tags: node.js, react-native, oauth, axios

Tried to get accesstoken from Restful API (Axios with React-native), however, only to get errormessage:

> "error": "unauthorized","error_description": "Full authentication is
>   required to access this resource"

```
function accessToken(){

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'myurl',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },

        data: {
            client_id: 'myid',
            client_secret: 'mysecret',
            grant_type: 'client_credentials'
        },


    })
        .then(function(res){

            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);

        })
        .catch(function(err) {

            console.log(err);
            console.log(err.response.data);
            console.log(err.response.status);
            console.log(err.response.headers);
            console.log(err.request);
            console.log(err.message);
            console.log(err.config);
        });
}

 Object {

   "error": "unauthorized",

   "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",

}
```

401

I tried to get accesstoken from Restful API made of Oauth. However I only to get error 401 with

> "Full authentication is required to access this resource".

I already tried to

```
   add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' in headers,  
   base64 encode id and pw,
   add withCredential : true and false,
   create instance with axios.create.
```

Here is example usage of the API.
the other functions which I made with Axios in React-native work well, however only this function which is supposed to get accesstoken does not work.

```
curl -X POST \

http://api_domain:port/oauth/token \

-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \

-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \

-d 'client_id=00002&client_secret=gateway-api-secret&grant_type=client_credentials'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this your server? Are there instructions for what the request is expecting? Probably an authorization header https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

Comment: @azium the api is not mine, i expects the result as below

{
    "access_token": "blabla",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": blabla,
    "scope": "read write trust"
}

Comment: yes but what does the api expect as the REQUEST?

Comment: @azium as you see the example usage, it requires POST

Comment: @azium https://api.segway.pt/doc/index.html, here it is

Comment: @jotkey - I realize this thread is old, but did you ever figure out the specific cause? Tx

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the username and password in auth header like

```
 method: "post",
  url: `myurl`,
  data: data,
  auth: {
    username: "myid",
    password: "mysecret"
  }
```

The **data** will have additional fields like grant_type etc.